# How to make a PolarPlot with different ranges of the angular coordinate for each curve?

Tags: plotting

I want to create a single `PolarPlot` containing the two unit circle arcs connecting 1 with the other two cubic roots of unity. If I wanted to create two separate plots, I could use, say,

```
PolarPlot[1, {t, 0,  2Pi/3}, PlotStyle -> Red]
PolarPlot[1, {t, 0, -2Pi/3}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

What should I do if I want to draw both arcs on the same plot?

Comment: Use `Show[%,%%]` to view both curves.

Comment: @Atx: Thank you very much!